# How to import JUnit tests from one Maven project into another?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have two Eclipse projects A and B that I use to run Selenium tests with JUnit.

- Project A tests a web app, so it contains tests that are divided into multiple packages each with their own test suite class (one package for each feature).
- Project B tests an application that uses A's web app but adds new features, so it contains its own tests but must also be able to reuse tests from A in its own test suite class when features are reused.

In both projects, my test code is located under `src/test/java`, because I need to be able to test both separately.

The problem is that I can't reuse tests from `A` in `B` because I can't import the test packages from `A`. I tried to fix this by placing `A`'s packages in its `src/main/java` folder instead, but that means I can no longer run `A`'s test suites separately because it no longer has any tests to speak of.

What I want to do is to simply have tests in my Project A, that I can execute, but to be able to reuse those test classes in Project B without duplicating code. How can I do this?

Comment: you may like to have a look into this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package your test code in its own artifact

```
 <!-- Packaging of test classes in JAR file -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You can then import the dependency where you need it